# Api rate limiting on azure functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, rate-limiting

I am trying to rate limit my azure functions wrt IP address of the user. I am trying to use AspNetCoreRateLimit package used for .Net core 3.1 for WebAPI but it doesnt work for Azure function which are HTTP triggered.
I know it can be done with API management but that will incur some cost with it. I was wondering if there are any alternatives to this package or any other method to IP rate limit the calls.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Azure API Management has a reasonably new (2019) _Consumption plan_ which is much more attactive (_[First 1 million calls free per month per Azure subscription = $0.00](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)_)

Comment: I can work with that. Thanks @MickyD

Comment: @MickyD IP throttling is unavailable for consumption plan :(

Comment: Awwww man....Darn

Answer (score 0):

[ThrottlingTroll](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll) now supports both Azure Functions (.NET Isolated) and Azure Functions with ASP.NET Core Integration.

And you can have custom IdentityIdExtractors to limit based on client IP addresses (or anything else).

[Here is an example](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/ThrottlingTroll.AzureFunctions#to-limit-clients-based-on-their-identityid).

Comment: But this does not support .NET 6.

Comment: @CrazyCrab, it's true, the earliest .NET version for ThrottlingTroll.AzureFunctions is .NET 7. And that's intentional. Technically nothing should prevent you to migrate your Functions from .NET 6 to .NET 7.